# Deadlocks and slowness for some users in my endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

we developped a .net core Web Api that will be utilised for ordering products , I have some wired issues in the production environment because the application slows down randomly for some users.
the exact problem within our application is a function that uses semaphoreSlim within a Concurency ductionay ( here the implementation [here](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-lock-threads-async-custom-ids-lockprovider/) .
i ran an intensive load test on the function and the result end up with the lost of some requests
for exp: if i run 1000 request at the same time only 960 will be processed.
my function code goes like this :

```
 await LockProvider<string>.WaitAsync( request.ProductCode , cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

         var org = await _currentOrganization.GetCurrentOrganizationIdAsync();
        if (!org.HasValue)
        {
            //_logger.Error($"Organization id is empty, command: {nameof(UpdateOnHandQuantityCommand)}");
            //sem.Release();
            LockProvider<string>.Release(request.ProductCode);
            return new ValidationResult
            {
                Errors = { new ValidationFailure("User Not valid ", "User not assigned to any organization") }
            };
        }
       
        using (var dbContext = _factory.Invoke())
        {
            var existingDim = await dbContext
                .Set<InventSum>()
                //.AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.InternalBatchNumber == request.InternalBatchNumber &&
                                          x.ProductCode == request.ProductCode
                                          && x.OrganizationId == org,
                    cancellationToken);
            if (existingDim == null)
            {
              LockProvider<string>.Release(request.ProductCode);
                return new ValidationResult
                {
                    Errors =
                    {
                        new ValidationFailure("Stock not found",
                            $"InventSum with {request.InternalBatchNumber} wasn't found")
                    }
                };
            }
            try
            {
                string key = existingDim.ProductId.ToString() + org;
                existingDim.PhysicalOnhandQuantity = request.PhysicalOnHandQuantity;
                // dbContext.Set<InventSum>().Update(existingDim);
                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                var inventSum = await _redisCache.GetAsync<InventSumCreatedEvent>(key, cancellationToken);
                var indexOfExistingDim = inventSum.CachedInventSumCollection.CachedInventSums
                    .FindIndex(t => t.ProductId == existingDim.ProductId
                                    && t.InternalBatchNumber == existingDim.InternalBatchNumber
                                    && t.OrganizationId == org.Value);
                inventSum.CachedInventSumCollection.CachedInventSums[indexOfExistingDim].PhysicalOnhandQuantity = request.PhysicalOnHandQuantity;
                await _redisCache.AddOrUpdateAsync<InventSumCreatedEvent>(key, inventSum, cancellationToken);
        LockProvider<string>.Release(request.ProductCode);
```

Comment: You said you meet slowness issue, I think you can use debugdiag to collect performance dump to analyze.

Comment: And you also mentioned that `if i run 1000 request at the same time only 960 will be processed.`. Is there something wrong when you using `SemaphoreSlim`.  Pls show more details about `SemaphoreSlim`, and we can help you.

Comment: i figured out what was the probleme  the cause of the problem is this line in the implementation of slimsemaphore :                                                                 
 public void Release(T idToUnlock)
        {
            SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
            if (lockDictionary.TryGetValue(idToUnlock, out semaphore))
                semaphore.Release();
        } , i convert it to : LockDictionary.GetOrAdd(idToUnlock, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)).Release();